# Add subview to custom UITableViewCell programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, frame

I have custom `UITableViewCell` and have couple of subviews added to it. I am using `Auto Layout`. I need to add another subview to the cell but without using `Auto Layout` (so that I can move left and right with a `pan gesture`). When I add it it gets wrong height (bigger than wanted). I am inspecting the height of the cell also and it is smaller than the height of the `contentView`. Here is my code:

```
class IntervalCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func createThumb() {

        let height = self.frame.size.height - 20
        let width = height * 0.7
        let originY: CGFloat = 0
        let originX = sliderView.frame.origin.x - width / 2

        let thumbFrame = CGRect(x: originX, y: originY, width: width, height: height)

        let testView = UIView(frame: thumbFrame)
        testView.backgroundColor = .red
        self.contentView.addSubview(testView)

    }

}
```

Because of `let height = self.frame.size.height - 20` it is supposed that the subview will have height that is just part of the screen but it actually is bigger than the height of the whole cell. `crateThumb` is called in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

Comment: You *can* use auto-layout even when you want to move a view with pan gestures. That can help a lot with sizing, and makes it much easier to handle size changes (such as with device rotation).

Comment: if you need it inside didSelect , then it should have correct frame , also set clipsToBounds = true

Comment: @DonMag Yes. I think I will be able to use it with `Auto Layout`. I had an issue before, but I was making a transform and also updating an image. (this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280086/view-moves-weirdly-on-rotation-through-pan-gesture ) . But now I just have to move it left or right, so It will probably work with constraints. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned `crateThumb` is called in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` it means that your `UITableViewCell` subclass has not yet been sized by `autolayout`, thus your `cell` has height lets say `44` when `crateThumb` is called but when the cell is sized it is only `30` px in height, thus your `testView` will be too big.

You can do the following:

1) call `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before calling ``crateThumb()`

2) in your sublcass `layoutSubviews()`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let thumbView = ...//somehow get your thumb view and change its height/width
}
```

Note: to get your thumbView you could add a property to your subclass or assign it a custom tag:

```
let testView = UIView(frame: thumbFrame)
testView.tag = 100
```

Then you can get it with:

```
if let thumbView = contentView.viewWithTag(100) {
      //modify thumbViews height/width
}
```